# Intellij IDEA 14 Ultimate cursor jumping around in Java Code when hitting Enter from time to time

Tags: intellij-idea

Sometimes when i hit `Enter` behind a line to write the next line my cursor jumps down like 300 lines of code within the same Java class which is absolutly annoying.

It jumps just to anywhere within the same file but always somewhere faar below the line i hit enter behind ... so its not jumping to a definition or something like that - it literally just places the cursor to a random point.

Did anyone ever had a similar experience? (I cant find anything on the internet hence i think its either a very easy to fix thing or something for the support).

Like could this be a side effect of defined live templates or something like that?
ANY suggestion could help since i tried out anything i could think of (code completion, live templates, editor settings - nothing looks like it would trigger this behaviour)

**Note: I dont like this question at all but i am realy lost right now.**

Comment: Never encountered this before.  You'd have to provide a ton more specifics about this since it's unclear how this could be happening.

Comment: @Makoto i agree a 100% and will probably just reinstall the entire setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not seen any one run into this nor have I seen a bug report on such (and something like that would be a critical). I recommend the following steps:

1. Upgrade to the latest v14.0.3 if you are not at that version
2. Invalidate your caches and restart, then wait for IntelliJ to re-index your project (this is a bit of a long shot, but worth the couple of minutes it takes)

   - File/Application > Invalidate Cache
3. Disable all third party (i.e. non-bundled) plug-ins and restart

   - My strongest suspicion is that a 3rd party plug-in is causing the issue.
   - If this solves the issue, isolate the plug-in causing the issue and contact the developer.
4. If none of the above work, provide as much detail as you can about the issue as @Makoto suggests. What type of file; what are you doing; OS; IDEA version; etc, etc.

Comment: Thank you you took that time - I will try the above points and reinstall the entire setup from scratch if does not solve the issue.

Comment: Dudes (or Gentlemen if you prefer the former) my keyboard was broke and the page down button sometimes triggered when i hit enter rofl :D thanks for the help anyways I realy appreciate the effort even on such "phantom error questions"